# How do I control the execution flow so the ng-repeat completes before the parent directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

I'd like **extend-item** directive to run **after** **ng-repeat** is rendered in DOM.
In the example below the ^ is added only to the static ul elements, since the dynamic ul elements are not yet generated by ng-repeat yet. **See code in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qM0EkkSgC0OddDnKraTJ?p=preview)**
**How do I control the execution flow so the ng-repeat completes before the parent directive?**

```html
<ul id="nav" ng-controller="AppController as vm" extend-item>
  <li ng-repeat="group in vm.groups">
    <a href="/{{group.id}}"><span>{{group.name}}</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
        <a href="/{{item.id}}"><span>{{item.name}}</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <!-- Static -->
  <li>
    <a href="/10"><span>Static Group 10</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/11"><span>Static 11</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app')
    .directive('extendItem', extendItem);

  extendItem.$inject = ['$compile'];
  /* @ngInject */
  function extendItem($compile) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      var $lists = element.find('ul').parent('li');

      $lists.append('<i>^</i>');
      console.log('extendItem - $lists length: ' + $lists.length);
    }
  }
})();
```

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app')
    .controller('AppController', AppController);

  AppController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  /* @ngInject */
  function AppController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.groups = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Group 1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Group 2'
    }];

    vm.items = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Item 1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Item 2'
    }];

    activate();

    ///////////////////////////////

    function activate() {
      console.log('AppController');
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is use `$timeout` before executing your code: this will wait for the current digest cycle to be done and the DOM to be refreshed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/KVlzZHHwa3ECxteJBvD8?p=preview

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
  $timeout(function() {
    var $lists = element.find('ul').parent('li');

    $lists.append('<i>^</i>');
    console.log('extendItem - $lists length: ' + $lists.length);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with $timeout is that it will only work the first time your DOM is evaluated and relies on your model never changing.  If your model changes (i.e, you add groups), the new groups will not have the ^ appended.

[Here is a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kZDmUBniWxYa6VnKchyS?p=preview) that demonstrates this problem.

[I would instead use css (if you are using a modern browser)](http://plnkr.co/edit/6s8Wtr6fguTervXV2zEM?p=preview)

```
<style>
    ul[extend-item] > li::after {
      content: '^'
    }
</style>
```

In general, any time you find yourself wanting to modify the DOM after ng-repeat "completes" or "is rendered", you are thinking about it "wrong" in the Angular sense.  ng-repeat never "completes".  It is always watching the model and can potentially add or remove elements based on changes in the model.  Using $timeout does not guarantee that the DOM will not be modified at some time in the future.

You might want to also investigate using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end for this particular use case, especially if the intent is to add more than just simple content after each list element.

[From the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> To repeat a series of elements instead of just one parent element,
>   ngRepeat (as well as other ng directives) supports extending the range
>   of the repeater by defining explicit start and end points by using
>   ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end respectively. The ng-repeat-start
>   directive works the same as ng-repeat, but will repeat all the HTML
>   code (including the tag it's defined on) up to and including the
>   ending HTML tag where ng-repeat-end is placed.